# error MSB3073: The command "chmod +x IntuneMAMConfigurator" on xamarin ios app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, intune

after installing (Microsoft.Intune.MAM.Xamarin.iOS) plugin to use Microsoft intune in xamarin ios app, on visual studio 2019
I get the error below

```
2>  chmod +x IntuneMAMConfigurator
2>  /var/folders/ls/1k0kn5wn16nby860m50dxj4w0000gn/T/tmp6f8c6a724230450983e1c0213a9f3337.exec.cmd: line 1: setlocal: command not found
2>  /var/folders/ls/1k0kn5wn16nby860m50dxj4w0000gn/T/tmp6f8c6a724230450983e1c0213a9f3337.exec.cmd: line 5: exit: %errorlevel%: numeric argument required
2>C:\Users\yhadhoud\.nuget\packages\microsoft.intune.mam.xamarin.ios\14.3.5\build\xamarinios10\Microsoft.Intune.MAM.Xamarin.iOS.targets(23,5): error MSB3073: The command "chmod +x IntuneMAMConfigurator" exited with code 255.
```

The reference I was following [Click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/developer/app-sdk-xamarin#enabling-intune-app-protection-polices-in-your-ios-mobile-app)

Note: Before installing this plugin the app works fine.

my **Entitlemnts.plist**

[image]

Comment: Try to remove the temp files and also remove the nuget package.

Comment: i tried but it didn't work

Comment: Are you using mac or windows?

Comment: I use windows, And I found the solution, after a great effort in working on the problem, it turned out that the problem is very simple, it is to update the Visual Studio, I feel frustrated , thank you